# R GARCH simulation providing whole components (y, cond.vol. etc.)

Tags: programming, garch

`fGarch::garchSim` provides only realizations of `y` variable, is there way to obtain also conditional variance and time series of errors ?

`garchSim(extended=TRUE)` makes the case

Comment: Are you answering your own question with `garchSim(extended=TRUE) makes the case`? If so, add it as answer.